# Oracle forms trigger after pressing a button

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I created a textbox and a button. What I wanted to happen is that after pressing the button and the textbox is null, the focus must go back on textbox.

```
BEGIN       
   IF :blk.textbox IS NULL THEN
        msg_alert('Error message', 'E', FALSE);
   end if;    
END;
```

I'd already tried to put the code above in WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger but nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your code in WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM trigger of :BLK.TEXTBOX item.

```
BEGIN       
    IF :blk.textbox IS NULL THEN
        msg_alert('Error message', 'E', FALSE);

        --if msg_alert procedure has no RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE, then uncomment next line
        -- RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
   end if;    

END;
```

You can also set the MOUSE NAVIGATE property to FALSE (or NO) of the button so that the focus won't go to that button after it was clicked.

use GO_ITEM also to set the focus to the textitem. sample,

```
GO_ITEM('blk.textbox');
```

Comment: that's also an option dude but what i wanted is to make the focus from button to textbox

Comment: use GO_ITEM to set the focus to the textitem

Comment: i tried it too dude and the focus is still on the button

Comment: did you put GO_ITEM before MSG_ALERT or after it? Does MSG_ALERT procedure has RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE?

Comment: i tried to place it too before and after but got the same result.

Comment: i see, well, there must be something that preventing it to focus on the TEXT_ITEM or there must be something that makes the focus go back to the button. also, try to remove the MSG_ALERT code and see what happens. check also the item type, it should not be a display item.

Comment: still not focusing dude.

Answer (score 1):

Why reinventing the wheel? Set text item's `REQUIRED` property to `YES`.

After reading comments you left for @eifla001's answer, I'm not sure what is the code you have. Something like this works properly on my Forms 10g (but should work on *any* version):

```
-- WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger 
if :blk.textbox is null then
   go_item('blk.textbox');
end if;
```

If it doesn't work, check TEXTBOX's properties. Is it really a text (or a display) item? Is it enabled? Are there any `SET_ITEM_PROPERTY` calls that make it unavailable?

Because, task you're about to perform is really *trivial*, that should work *just like that*.

Comment: It's you again dude! I'd intentionally set the REQUIRED property to NO so that I can show a msg_alert if that textbox is null. If you set the REQUIRED property to YES, there's no way you can leave the textbox empty. Also, it's a textbox and enabled.

Comment: As of the REQUIRED property: OK, I understand. As of trigger code I posted: did you try it? What happened?

Comment: Yes dude I tried it too. I set the REQUIRED property to YES then clicked the button and like I predicted, it wont go out of the textbox if its null. Then property to NO, the focus still wont go to the textbox

Comment: That's strange, really ... Just to make sure: did you use GO_BLOCK **exactly** as I wrote it? Single quotes, block name must **NOT** have a colon in front of its name. Did you correctly spell block & item name?

Comment: Thanks again dude! My bad I saw a ':' LOL

Comment: OK then, you fixed it.